# Add span class according to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have a span attribute and need to insert a class to force hide it if it is inside a url, I want to do it in javascript entirely.

Code i'm doing

```
function exec()
{ 
    url = window.location.href; 
    if(url == "https://www.myurl.com.br/product")
    {
        $("span .price").addClass("force-hide");
    }
}
```

Html code

```
<div class="info-details"> 
<strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> Long Drink Unicórnio Seja Você </a> 
</strong>
<div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
</span> 
</span> 
</div></div>
```

I want to make sure that if it is in the indicated url, add a force-hide class in the span price attribute.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask your question...

Comment: How to add it to the <span class = "price"> class force-hide if it is in the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Note that className is a single string. If you're adding more than one class they need to be separated with spaces.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="price">price</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let url = window.location;
        if( url == "https://your.domain.here"){
            document.getElementById('price').className += 'hide';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added an event listener to wait for the DOM to be ready.

Hope this works now.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if(window.location.href === "https://www.myurl.com.br/product") {
    document.querySelector('span.price').classList.add('force-hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.force-hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-details">
  <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> Long Drink Unicórnio Seja Você </a> 
</strong>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it is close to what I need, the idea is that the selected page will be <span class = "price force-hide"> and thus make this value hide.

Comment: So you want to hide the price for a section when it is on the section URL ?

Comment: That's it! Bibberty

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
    {
        exec();
        function exec()
        { 
            url = window.location.href; 
            if(url == "https://www.myurl.com.br/product")
            {
                $("span.price").addClass(" force-hide");
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
.force-hide{
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="info-details"> 
        <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
        <a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> Long Drink Unicórnio Seja Você </a> 
        </strong>
        <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
        <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
        <span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
        <span class="price">R$13,90</span>
        </span> 
        </span> 
        </div></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Basically you are missing a space inside addClass method, and the calling method exec().

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
            <style type="text/css">
            .force-hide{
                display: none;
            }
            </style>
        </head>

<body>
<div class="info-details"> 
        <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
        <a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> Long Drink Unicórnio Seja Você </a> 
        </strong>
        <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
        <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
        <span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
        <span class="price">R$13,90</span>
        </span> 
        </span> 
        </div></div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        exec();
        function exec()
        { 
            url = window.location.href; 
            if(url == "https://www.myurl.com.br/product")
            {
                $("span.price").addClass(" force-hide");
            }
        }
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```